# How to use Windows environment variable within a git commit message

Tags: windows, mac, bash, git

On the Mac, this substitutes username "mac" in the message:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
git init
echo "1">>1.txt
git add .
git commit --message="@${USER} whatever"
git log
```

But what is the equivalent on Windows? I would like to insert the Windows computer name because that information is not tracked automatically within Git:

```
git commit --message="%COMPUTERNAME% etc"
```

In a git custom command script, it would be:

```
git commit --message="%COMPUTERNAME%: $1"
```

(I know that I can vary the Git user name, but that would mess us other systems).

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand if you have tried the solution that you propose, but it is the correct one:

> git status -u="%COMPUTERNAME% etc"

```
fatal: Invalid untracked files mode '=HERPADERP etc'
```

My dosvar.bat file contains

```
echo on
mkdir temp
cd temp
git init
echo "1" >> 1.txt
git add 1.txt
git commit --message="%COMPUTERNAME% commited 1.txt"
git log
echo off
```

And when I run that

```
F:\scratch>echo on
F:\scratch>mkdir temp
F:\scratch>cd temp
F:\scratch\temp>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in F:/scratch/temp/.git/
F:\scratch\temp>echo "1"  1>>1.txt
F:\scratch\temp>git add 1.txt
F:\scratch\temp>git commit --message="HERPADERP commited 1.txt"
[master (root-commit) 4875a24] HERPADERP commited 1.txt
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 1.txt
F:\scratch\temp>git log
commit 4875a24cc23982e1914276054169fbdaa44442ac
Author: xxxxxx <xxxxxxxx>
Date:   Sat Apr 29 12:32:57 2017 -0700
    HERPADERP commited 1.txt
F:\scratch\temp>echo off
```

Comment: OP is asking how to do it?

Comment: I answered how I did it on a Windows machine